# Ошибка 500 в phpmailer при отправке формы

Tags: php, phpmailer

В логах такая ошибка:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception:
> \xd0\x9d\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe
> \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c
> \xd1\x84\xd1\x83\xd0\xbd\xd0\xba\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8e mail(). in
> /home/c/co71217/public_html/mail/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php:1950\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> /home/c/co71217/public_html/mail/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1664):
> PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->mailSend('Date: Tue, 22 N...',
> '\xD0\x97\xD0\xB0\xD1\x8F\xD0\xB2\xD0\xBA\xD0...')\n#1
> /home/c/co71217/public_html/mail/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1500):
> PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend()\n#2
> /home/c/co71217/public_html/mail/sendmail.php(40):
> PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send()\n#3 {main}\n thrown in
> /home/c/co71217/public_html/mail/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line
> 1950

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setLanguage('ru', 'phpmailer/language/');
$mail->IsHTML(true);

// От кого
$mail->setFrom('mail@mail.ru');
// Кому отправить
$mail->addAddress('mail@gmail.com');
// Тема письма
$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с сайта';

// Тело письма
$body = '<h2>Заявка с сайта</h2>';

if(trim(!empty($_POST['name']))) {
    $body.='<p><strong>Имя:</strong> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
}
if(trim(!empty($_POST['phone']))) {
    $body.='<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>';
}
if(trim(!empty($_POST['email']))) {
    $body.='<p><strong>E-mail:</strong> '.$_POST['email'].'</p>';
}
if(trim(!empty($_POST['text']))) {
    $body.='<p><strong>Сообщение:</strong> '.$_POST['text'].'</p>';
}

$mail->Body = $body;

// Отправляем
if (!$mail->send()) {
    $message = 'Ошибка';
} else {
    $message = 'Данные отправлены!';
}

$response = ['message' => $message];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: научитесь читать логи или хотя бы оборачивать код в блок `try catch`

Comment: ArchDemon, в логах ошибка вывел ее в описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст в виде:

> \xd0\x9d\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe
> \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c
> \xd1\x84\xd1\x83\xd0\xbd\xd0\xba\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8e mail()

говорит о том, что ваша консоль не поддерживает UTF8 символы, и если всё это "безобразие" расшифровать получится:

> Невозможно запустить функцию mail()

Если сервер ваш, то гуглите/настраивайте, иначе обращайтесь к хостеру.